# C++ comparing vectors using any_of not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, compare

I have two vectors each containing a set of integers that I would like to compare to see if they have the same elements. I'm using 'any_of' in the algorithms library and would like to iterate through the elements in one vector and see if the element appears in another vector. Below is the code that is not working:

```
vector<int> test1 = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> test2 = {1,2,5,6};
for(int i=0;i<test1.size();i++)
{
    if(any_of(test2.begin(),test2.end(),[](int integer){return integer==test1[i];}))
    {
      cout << "you have an element in test1 that is also in test2" << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is the if statement, and if I compare 'integer' with a number written out (i.e. 1,2, etc) the loop executes fine. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "_Below is the code that is not working_" Not working.. How?

Comment: `test1` is not captured in your lambda. You can capture it by `[&]`. For more information, refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Comment: There also `set_intersection` in the [`<algorithm>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)  may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

in lambda's you have to capture the stuff you want to be inside from the outside. that is put it in the square brackets. for example like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){

  vector<int> test1({1,2,3,4});
  vector<int> test2({1,2,5,6});
  for(int i=0; i<test1.size(); i++){
    if(any_of(test2.begin(),test2.end(),[test1,i](int integer){return integer==test1[i];})){
      cout << "you have an element in test1 that is also in test2" << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i got that to compile and pump out the outputs. not sure if it does what you want tho...

Comment: Note: consider recommending capturing such classes, as `std::vector`, by reference, to avoid doing copies, of (potentially) large amounts of data.

Comment: the point here is to demonstrate to the user the bit that was wrong, not write optimal code. if that is needed then @user4581301's comment is more to the point.

Comment: I know that. It's that it's easier to learn good habits from a get go, than to unlearn bad habits. And in more than 90% of use cases, you would want to pass/capture containers by reference, due to the ease of doing so, and performance benefits, that it brings.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass i and test1 to the lambda expression as so:

vector test1 = { 1,2,3,4 };
    vector test2 = { 1,2,5,6 };

```
for (int i = 0; i < test1.size(); i++)
{
    if (any_of(test2.begin(), test2.end(), [&i,&test1](int integer) {return integer == test1[i]; }))
    {
        cout << "you have an element in test1 that is also in test2" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: consider recommending capturing such classes, as std::vector, by reference, to avoid doing copies, of (potentially) large amounts of data.

Comment: Instead of capturing `i` and `test1`, see if you can rework your example to capture `test[i]`.